# Making a POST request in fulfillment in dialogflow

Tags: node.js, firebase, dialogflow-es

I am trying to make an HTTP post call to GitHub's API using DialogFlow's Fulfilment inline editor. Here is my code:

```
// See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
// for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');


process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

var github = require('request');
github.post({
  headers: {'User-Agent' : 'dummy-gh-user', 'Authorization': 'token ****'},
  url:     'https://api.github.com/repos/dummy-gh-user/dummy-gh-repo/issues',
  json:    
  {
  "title": "This is a bug",
  "body": "I'm having a problem with this.",
  "assignees": [
    "dummy-gh-user"
  ],
  "labels": [
    "bug"
  ]
}
}, function(error, response, body){
  console.log(body);
});

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }

  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

The above code gets deployed and saved and I do not get any errors in the firebase console. The `dummy-gh-user` is replaced by my github username. I've added my code to the existing fullfillment code.

Any thoughts as to why this code isnt working?

Comment: The code for the github POST works on my local environment perfectly fine.

Comment: Not sure what changed. But the same code is working today.